# error in sqlite3_prepare_v2 statement

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have this code, where the sqlite3_prepare_v2 statement is not returning OK... any ideas why?

```
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM CardData";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *saveDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [saveDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ppcipher.s3db"];

//  [dm openDatabaseWithPassword:password];  //  open the d/b   

    sqlite3 *database;
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_key(database,password,9);
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possibilities:

1. The `databasePath` is incorrect, and you are creating a new database rather than opening the one you think; see [sqlite3_open_v2](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) and `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY` to detect this
2. The schema does not contain a `CardData` table. Try printing out the schema with `select * from sqlite_master;`
3. The `password` is incorrect, and the database cannot be decrypted

Answer (score 0):

I believe the third argument in sqlite3_prepare_v2 is

> "Maximum length of zSql in bytes"

and you have -1 set there.  Maybe try setting it to

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, strlen(sqlStatement), &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
```